# Where is the auto correction in TeXnicCenter

Tags: automation, texniccenter

I was looking for the auto correction in TeXniCenter, and found a ticket from 2009 here: http://sourceforge.net/p/texniccenter/user-reports/1066/

Tino Weinkauf said: "It is already in our feature list" but I can't find it anywhere. Am I blind, or is it actually missing?

I want that, everytime I type `nm$`, it changes to `\,$nm`. Is there any possibility to do that?

Answer (score 1):

No, at the present time that has not been implemented.  However, you can check if the [feature request](http://sourceforge.net/p/texniccenter/feature-requests/) is still in order.

Furthermore, for the particular use you want, you could use a different type of program for this, such as [Robotype](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2380508,00.asp&ei=2-FbUqu1Nqr17AbF5IBo&usg=AFQjCNF8lQ3jphnurnqUG55flhY31r1ORQ&sig2=ceCfHV1JcJFi88RckXi8jA&bvm=bv.53899372,d.Yms&cad=rja).  This will allow you to type chunks of characters by just typing a few of them (whatever you set them to be).

It is fully customizable and I think this might be just what you are looking for.  It is more of a typing-text related solution rather than TeXnicCenter's.